# Fullcalendar 6 :Consecutive events don't always take up the total width of the day column

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using fullcalendar 6. I noticed that consecutive events don't always take up the total width of the days column.

**Below is my issue:**
[image]
I noticed that this offset is only visible if the start and end date of the event is not equal to the duration slot (weekly Team2 event).

**JS code**

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { 
    nowIndicator: true,
    eventOverlap:false,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },
    initialDate: new Date(y, m, 2),
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    events: [
      {
        title: "Daily Team 1",
        start: new Date(y, m, 2, 7, 00),
        end: new Date(y, m, 2, 7, 20),
        allDay: false
      },
      {
        title: "Weekly Team 2",
        start: new Date(y, m, 2, 7, 20),
        end: new Date(y, m, 2, 8, 20),
        allDay: false
      },
      {
        title: "Sprint review Team 3",
        start: new Date(y, m, 2, 8, 20),
        end: new Date(y, m, 2, 9, 40),
        allDay: false
      },
      {
        title: "Daily Team 2",
        start: new Date(y, m, 3, 7, 00),
        end: new Date(y, m, 3, 7, 30),
        allDay: false
      },
      {
        title: "Daily Team 3",
        start: new Date(y, m, 3, 7, 30),
        end: new Date(y, m, 3, 8, 0),
        allDay: false
      },
      {
        title: "Weekly Team 1",
        start: new Date(y, m, 3, 8, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, 3, 9, 30),
        allDay: false
      },
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJdNeZE . From your pictures it looks like you might have applied some custom CSS to your page. Possibly this is the cause of your issue. Either that, or your events are actually overlapping and not purely consective. If you need further assistance please provide us with a [mre] of your issue including relevant code and sample event data in JSON format. We cannot fix pictures alone. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You seem to be right about the consecutive events where the times don't align with the slot times. And indeed we can see if we adjust it by one minute then the issue goes away: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWLeWZg . Although you can also see from my altered version of the data that it will occur on the duration line as well. What the pattern _seems_ to be is it can occur when the first event in the pair is shorter than the duration of a single slot.

Comment: I'd now say that this is a bug in fullCalendar, and as such there's not much we can do about it on Stackoverflow - we can help you with implementation and integration, but we can't fix the internals. Follow the procedure at https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs to raise the issue with the fullcalendar team.